# MongoDB Nodejs inserting error with update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im using upsert option so items that doesn't exists will be inserted but i am getting this error, it works fine when im updating existing item

```
MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: options.$.votes
```

here's update

```
 db.collection('polls').update(
               { _id:  require("mongodb").ObjectId(id), "options.key": item },
               { $inc: { "options.$.votes" : 1 } }, 
               {upsert: true, safe: false},
               function(err, data){
                   if(err) throw err;

                   if(data){
                       console.log(data)
                   }
               }
            )
```

Here is the sample data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5aae26203ab1cc0f15e43dc6"
    },
    "author": "me",
    "title": "fruits you love the most",
    "options": [
        {
            "key": "banana",
            "votes": 4
        },
        {
            "key": "apple",
            "votes": 6
        },
        {
            "key": "mango",
            "votes": 11
        },
        {
            "key": "grapes",
            "votes": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Here $ is not working because query didn't return anything.
As error say it.. MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh yes... but i have upsert that's why i am confuse why it's not inserting instead throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#behavior). You cannot use `$` with `upsert` operation.

I think you need 2 seperate query to check if `options.key` is present before `$inc` its votes with update query. Or `$push` to array if it's not exist.

Comment: That's odd... most resources i found here on stackoverflow follow the same code but it work for them.. hmmm

Comment: Can you post the link you've found, I think most the case they're using `$inc` is for increase value of object not inside the array.